# In R how to mutate a numeric column into one new column using various conditions?

Tags: r, dplyr, survival-analysis

I am trying to make a new column in a dataframe based on the value of an original column where it is split into four groups each based on a different condition of the value. I can't figure out how to do this!

Assume a column with a score (numeric value 0-1000) as part of a larger dataframe.

I want to make a new column grouping that score based on the following conditions:

- Those that have a score of 0
- Those between 0 and 33rd percentile
- Those between 33rd and 66th percentile
- Those between 66th and 100 percentile

I want the new column to be something like "Score_status" and to label them "none", "low", "middle", "high" according to the above conditions. The percentiles need to be calculated ignoring all the 0s, as when split into quantiles both Q1 and Q2 are 0, hence trying to make this new column to see the spread of data outside of score 0 (this is for a Kaplan-Meier).

I hope someone can help! I can't quite get my head around how I would do this.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that map the value to the label. That allow you to compute cut point on a subset of your data in the function.

An example of an (inefficient) implementation:

```
cut_with_none <- function(x, none_value, none_label, quant, break_labels) {
  y <- x == none_value
  q_val <- quantile(x[!y], quant)
  res <- vector(mode = "character", length = length(x))
  for(i in rev(seq_along(q_val))) {
    res[x <= q_val[i]] <- break_labels[i]
  }
  
  res[y] <- none_label
  
  res
}
```

Where:

- none_value: the value you wants to label as none
- none_label: the label for none value
- quant: a vector of numeric between 0 and 1 pass to quantile to compute breaks value
- break_labels: a vector of name as long as quant vector for labels.

You can add your column with the function easily using mutate.

For example with random data:

```
tibble(subject = sample(letters[1:3], 10, replace = TRUE),
           value = rgeom(10, 0.5)) %>% 
  mutate(label_value = cut_with_none(value, 0, "none", 
                                     quant = c(1/3, 2/3, 1),
                                     break_labels = c("low", "middle", "high")))
```

Hope that do the trick's even if it's not elegant at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach using `cut`. Create an index `idx` that would contain the row numbers of 0 values to be omitted from percentile evaluation.  Below is a quick example with random data (one value is zero).

```
set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(
  var = sample(0:9, 10)
)

idx <- df$var != 0

df$score_status <- factor(NA_character_, levels = c("none", "low", "middle", "high"))

df$score_status[idx] <- cut(
  df$var[idx],
  breaks = quantile(df$var[idx], probs = c(0, 1/3, 2/3, 1)), 
  include.lowest = TRUE,
  labels = c("low", "middle", "high")
)

df$score_status[!idx] <- "none"

df
```

**Output**

```
   var score_status
1    0         none
2    4       middle
3    9         high
4    7         high
5    1          low
6    3          low
7    5       middle
8    8         high
9    6       middle
10   2          low
```